# Understanding Spark UI for a streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-ui

I am trying to understand what the entries in my Spark UI signify.

[image]

Calling an action results in creation of a job. I am finding hard to understand

1. How many of these jobs get created? and is that proportional to the number of micro-batches?
2. What does the Duration column signify?
3. What is the effect of setting the batch duration when instantiating the streaming context? Where is that visible in the Spark UI?

> new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(50))

Answer (score 0):

1.The jobs are proportional to the micro batches,say your streaming context time is 50 sec ,then you will have 2 jobs in a minute

2.Duration, specifies the amount of time taken to process a single micro batch or job.Ideally the duration taken to process a micro batch should be less than time specified for the micro batches.Say if its 50sec , each micro batch job should be complete well within that time

3.When you take the streaming option in the UI when the job is running , you can see that each micro batch is created in an interval of 50 sec

When you click on a job , you get the details of stages of that single micro-batch/job.I guess you have shared the screen hot of the same.Here the duration points to the time taken by each stage in the job to complete